# How to change the version of app in android studio

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have uploaded an app in Play Store before and now I created second version of that app and ready to upload in Play Store. I changed the version name and code in `build.gradle(Module:app)` from 1 to 2. It took that Version code but while uploading the app in google play console , But in Google Play Console It is showing that this version already exists. Change the version and upload again.

Comment: you must change version name also mate

Comment: what is your `versionCode` and `versionName` ??? please send me same as like in your `build.gradle`

Comment: show what exactly you changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In build.app  have youe changed both version code and version name

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sb.android.acg.test"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1      // update this
    versionName "1.0"  // update this
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

To answer Eric's question

1:find the "Project" toolbar (if you are using windows press Alt+1)
2:Inside Project make sure you have opened Android option and not project or any other(it's located on the top of the window you just opened)
3:Open "Gradle scripts"
4:Click build.gradle (Module:app)

Comment: Can't find a build.app file in my project in Android Studio 3.5.3. Where is it located?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, the solution worked for me. btw, versionCode must be a whole integer, such as 2, not 2.1...

Comment: @EricLangley It is a full integer, I guess you mistook it for versionName

Answer (score 1):

> It's very easy to do. Follow the simple steps

1. Right-click on the `app` folder ---> `Open Module Settings`

[image]

2. Select `Modules` from the left panel, under the `Default Config` tab, update the `Version Code` and `Version Name`.

[image]

Version Code always is an integer. You have to update it every time when you release new version of the application.

You can set the Version Name according to your needs. As an example, if you fix minor bugs or update, your Version Name like 2.1, 2.2, etc If you fix major bugs or add more features your Version Name should like 3.0, 4.0, etc.